# Showing context menu option if extension is not .aent

Tags: windows, shell, windows-registry, context-menu

I have made an application that can basically encrypt anything, I have added a registry entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell/ so that it's shown whenever one right clicks a file. but I don't want to show the option (encrypt in this case) if the file is already encrypted. The encrypted file has the extention '.aent'. how can I hide this option only for encrypted files?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens

Comment: @STTR the link you provided doesn't really address my issue.